# how to compile armadillo library with specified gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, armadillo

According the readme file in armadillo, after entering " cmake . " command, then enter " make " command, then print the following error information.

```
Scanning dependencies of target armadillo
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o
In file included from armadillo-4.100.2/src/wrapper.cpp:8:
armadillo-4.100.2/build_tmp/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_setup.hpp:125:6: error: #error "*** Need a newer compiler ***"
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/src/wrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/armadillo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I read the compiler_setup.hpp file. I find the failure is due to the default gcc is low. But hot to use my higher gcc to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

Make listens to environment variables, which you can also set on the command-line. Try

```
 $ CXX=g++-4.8 make
```

and g++-4.8 (if you have it) can be used.  Another trick is to use

```
 $ cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.8 g++
```

as the path in /usr/local/bin will be consulted first.

Comment: -- Configuring Armadillo 4.100.2
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME          = Linux
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID      = GNU
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION = 4.1.2
-- CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX   = 1
--    MKL_FOUND   = NO
-- ACMLMP_FOUND   = NO
--   ACML_FOUND   = NO
--   LAPACK_FOUND = NO
--     BLAS_FOUND = NO
-- OpenBLAS_FOUND = NO
--  CLAPACK_FOUND = NO
--    CBLAS_FOUND = NO
-- ARPACK_FOUND = NO
-- 
-- *** The run-time library component of Armadillo will use the following libraries:
-- *** ARMA_LIBS =

Comment: I try your first method. But it also does not work. For the second, I can not do it as I am not the root.